# " Undefined reference to mknod " How to resolve this?

Tags: c, windows, gcc, operating-system, system-calls

```
/*Creating a special file */
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int result;
    if (argc != 2) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: ./a.out fifoname\n");
        exit (1);
     }
    result = mknod (argv[1], S_IRUSR| S_IWUSR|S_IFIFO, 0);
    if (result < 0) {
        perror ("mknod");
        exit (2);
       }
  }
```

I have executed a sample code to create a special file in CodeBlocks which uses GCC compiler ...But the code runs properly in Ubuntu environment..
Is Windows environment creating the problem. If so, how to resolve the problem to run the program in Windows ?

Comment: `mknod()` is SVr4, 4.4BSD, POSIX.1-2001 function, neither of this supported by Windows, so this function simply doesn't exist in Windows standard library

Answer (score 0):

As qrdl pointed out, `mknod()` is a SVr4, 4.4BSD, POSIX.1-2001 function. But, you can include [CoreUtil](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/coreutils.htm)s to windows and, after adding the library to codeblock, you can use thoses functions.